# How to copy a single value in a dataframe to another dataframe in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a single value data frame.

avg(Cal1)
0.006747600000000001

Need to copy this single value as a column in in a new data frame. That data frame is having 10 rows. So need to copy this value 10 times in a new column in the second data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best bet is probably to just collect it and insert it with `withColumn`.

```scala
val average = df.select(avgCol).as[Double].collect.head  // your value here
val newDf = df2.withColumn("newCol", lit(average))
```

The alternative is to join it, but the first one should be more reasonable.